# Integrate $I(x) = \frac{1}{ 2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-Na}}{jt(1+jt)} e^{\frac{Na}{1+jt}} e^{jxt}dt $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions, contour-integration

I want to integrate:

$$I(x) = \frac{1}{ 2 \pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-Na}}{jt(1+jt)} e^{\frac{Na}{1+jt}} e^{jxt} \,dt $$

Where $j = \sqrt{-1}$, $a \in \mathbb{R_{++}}$ and $N \in \mathbb{Z_{++}}$

The solution is apparently:

$$ I(x) = e^{-Na} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-y} I_{0}(2 \sqrt{Nay})\,dy $$

where $I_{0}(\cdot)$ is the modified Bessel function of the 1st kind of order 0.

---

It looks like I should be going for an answer of the form:

$$I(x) = e^{-Na} \big( F(T) - F(0) \big)$$

Where $F(\cdot)$ is the antiderivative of $e^{-x} I_{0}(2 \sqrt{Nax})$ wrt x.

---

My approach:

We start off by taking out $e^{-Na}$ and writing $e^{\frac{Na}{1+jt}}$ as a power series. This gives us:

$$I(x) = \frac{e^{-Na}}{2 \pi} \displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{jt(1+jt)} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(Na)^{k}}{k! (1+jt)^{k}} e^{jxt} dt $$

Bringing the sum out and combining gives us:

$$I(x) = \frac{e^{-Na}}{2 \pi} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} 
\frac{(Na)^{k}}{k!}\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{(Na)^{k}}{jt(1+jt)^{k+1}} e^{jxt} dt $$

This is where I get stuck. The result of the integral is obviously the sum of the residues, but I can't seem to reconcile that with the stated result.

Can somebody help? What is that antiderivative anyway? I am quite lost here.

---

One interesting trick:

We have the Fourier transform pair:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{t} x(\gamma) d\gamma <-> \frac{1}{j\omega} X(\omega) + \pi X(0) \delta(\omega) $$

Where $X(\cdot)$ is the FT pair of $x(\cdot)$.

Comment: Does your integral converge?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I assume it does, as there is an answer given, however I have not checked. The question is, how do I get that answer?

Comment: And what if your assumptions are not true?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Then I am screwed haha. Fair enough point I suppose, however, the paper I am reading claims that the result posted can be found by examining pairs 210 and 655.1 in Campbell and Foster "Fourier Integrals for Practical Applications". I want to figure out how to do it from scratch, since I don't have that book.

Comment: The integrand has a pole at $t = 0$, and thus the integral is undefined on any contour that goes through it (such as the one you're currently integrating over). As such, you need to specify how you are handling that singularity (likely by taking the Cauchy principal value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to solve the following integral:

$$ I(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{jt(1+jt)} e^{\frac{-jNat}{1+jt}} e^{jxt} dt $$

To solve, we first recall a property of the Fourier transform. Namely:

$$ F^{-1}\big\{ \frac{G(t)}{jt}  \big\} = \int_{-\infty}^{x} g(\tau) d\tau $$

where $g(x)$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $G(t)$, and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(\tau) d\tau = 0$. Thus we only need to solve:

$$ I_{1}(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+jt} e^{\frac{-jNat}{1+jt}} e^{jxt} dt $$

So, we start solving this integral by noticing:

$$ e^{\frac{-jNat}{1+jt}} = e^{-Na} e^{\frac{Na}{1+jt}}  $$

Thus:

$$ I_{1}(x) = \frac{e^{-Na}}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+jt} e^{\frac{Na}{1+jt}} e^{jxt} dt $$

We use the power series of $e^{\frac{Na}{1+jt}}$ in the integral:

$$ I_{1}(x) = \frac{e^{-Na}}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+jt} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(Na)^{k}}{k!(1+jt)^{k}} e^{jxt} dt $$

Pulling out the constants and interchanging the sum and integral because the sum is convergent, we get:

$$ I_{1}(x) = \frac{e^{-Na}}{2 \pi} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(Na)^{k}}{k!} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+jt)^{k+1}} e^{jxt} dt $$

The integral is the inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{(1+jt)^{k+1}}$, which can be found either by the residue theorem using a contour in the upper half plane or by consulting Fourier tables. We get:

$$ I_{1}(x) = \frac{e^{-Na}}{2 \pi} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(Na)^{k}}{k!} \frac{2 \pi}{k!} x^{k} e^{-x} $$

Noting that:

$$I_{0}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)^{2k}}{k! \Gamma(k+1)}$$

Thus taking out the $e^{-x}$ and combining the powerts, we have:

$$ I_{1}(x) = e^{-x - Na} I_{0}(2 \sqrt{Nax})$$

So using the integration property of the Fourier transform mentioned earlier:

$$ I(x) = e^{-Na} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-y} I_{0}(2 \sqrt{Nay}) dy $$

since $I_{0}(x) = 0 \forall x <0$. This is the solution we were looking for.